# How to view the html code that is used to display hidden json data?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, youtube

I'm trying to see the source code of some hidden data encoded using JSON and then shown in a webpage. If I am correct,  javascript will process the data and then show it in the browser using html + css. I'm not interested in the data, but in the html and css that the javascript uses to display the encoded JSON data. I can't find it after hours of trying.

The website I'm experimenting on is YouTube and the data there is the comments. I can't find the the CSS and HTML that YouTube uses to display the comments. You can test on any video on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWsyrnOBsJs. What I tried:

1) Viewing the source code. All I got was that the comments are called from  div that has the  *id="comments-test-iframe"*. The code shown on YouTube site.

```
<div class="comments-iframe-container">
    <div id="comments-test-iframe"></div>
    <div id="distiller-spinner" class="action-panel-loading">
        <p class="yt-spinner">
      <img src="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" class="yt-spinner-img" alt="Loading icon">

    <span class="yt-spinner-message">
Loading...
    </span>
  </p>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

2) File **Save Page As > Web Page, Complete** in both Firefox and Chrome. Comments would still be retrieved but from YouTube. So I couldn't get to see the css and html that YouTube uses to display the comments.

3) I tried to install [Firebug 2.0](https://getfirebug.com/). I was able to see was the container used to display comments. again I couldn't see the html + css that is used to display the comments. What I got was only:

```
<div id="comments-test-iframe" style="text-indent: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none  repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; border-style: none; float: none; line-height: normal; font-size: 1px; vertical-align: baseline; display: inline-block; width: 591px; height: 5375px;">
```

which is the div element or container that YouTube uses to display the comments. But however no comments.

4) I tried to use [Html Clipper] (https://github.com/florentin/htmlclipper) which is a bookmarklet which lets you copy html sections of any web pages together with the attached css styles, it didn't work also.

How can I get to see that css+html? Is there an easy to save what the browser is displaying literally avoiding to go Firebug and inspect? I'm curious what is the trick that Google is using here also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code YouTube is generating is thus...

```
  <div class="comments-iframe-container">
    <div style="text-indent: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; border-style: none; float: none; line-height: normal; font-size: 1px; vertical-align: baseline; display: inline-block; width: 591px; height: 4799px;" id="comments-test-iframe"><iframe title="Comment on this" data-gapiattached="true" src="https://plus.googleapis.com/u/0/_/widget/render/comments?usegapi=1&amp;first_party_property=YOUTUBE&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DOWsyrnOBsJs&amp;owner_id=o5--boVIi-ow0xAU3VyxMg&amp;query=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DOWsyrnOBsJs&amp;stream_id=UCo5--boVIi-ow0xAU3VyxMg&amp;substream_id=OWsyrnOBsJs&amp;view_type=FILTERED&amp;width=590&amp;youtube_video_acl=PUBLIC&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com&amp;search=%3Fv%3DOWsyrnOBsJs&amp;hash=&amp;gsrc=1p&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Dgapi.gapi.en.TY07tiUU0tE.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItRSTNfGmB_-do3YO3g20AHt3L6itPzpQ#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Confirsttimeplusonepromo%2Conthumbsup%2Contimestampclicked%2Conready%2Conupgradeaccount%2Conallcommentsclicked&amp;id=I0_1403359704352&amp;parent=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com&amp;pfname=&amp;rpctoken=50836660" name="I0_1403359704352" id="I0_1403359704352" vspace="0" tabindex="0" style="position: static; top: 0px; width: 590px; margin: 0px; border-style: none; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 4799px;" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe></div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="distiller-spinner" class="action-panel-loading hid">
        <p class="yt-spinner">
      <img src="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" class="yt-spinner-img" alt="Loading icon">

    <span class="yt-spinner-message">
Loading...
    </span>
  </p>

    </div>
  </div>
```

The comments are shown with an iframe and are hosted on https://plus.googleapis.com.  This has security settings set up so you can't access them directly by going to that URL.  Firebug should allow you to inspect them within the YouTube page, however.  Not sure why you will have had difficulty doing that.

I have copied the iframe's code here: http://jsfiddle.net/dCYTA/ - firebug is probably also your friend here, as the raw code is pretty messy.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly... I've had luck with this method, though it may not be what you want.

I use Firefox/Aurora. I highlight the entire section with the outputted HTML and then right-click and select "View Selection Source." That allows me to see the HTML that is not shown when I just do a regular view source.